# Item selector does not work for Structure Groups in SDL Web 8.5

Tags: web8.5, sdl-tridion, itemselector

We are using the Item selector we found in the below github link for our application:
https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Item%20Selector/trunk/SDLTridion.Examples.ItemSelector

It works fine for CT's. However, for structure groups, once we click on the publication in the item selector pop-up, it does not display the Structure Groups in it.
We noticed that the URL for the pop has "type=1"  for publication, instead of 4 for Structure group:
[../ItemSelectorCustom/ItemSelectorPopup.htm?types=1](http://../ItemSelectorCustom/ItemSelectorPopup.htm?types=1)

For CT's however, the URL is :
[../ItemSelectorCustom/ItemSelectorPopup.htm?types=32](http://../ItemSelectorCustom/ItemSelectorPopup.htm?types=32), when we click on the link to item selector pop-up.

Please could you kindly help find, what and where to update so that the itemType is 4, to enable viewing of Structure groups.

TIA

Answer (score 2):

The code is licensed under the Reciprocal Public License 1.5 (RPL1.5) so you can easily download the source and try and figure out for yourself. The code can be found [here](https://github.com/bkoopman/sdl-tridion-world/tree/master/Item%20Selector/trunk). Once you play around with it a bit, please edit you question with some additional details like, what have you tried so far, if there is an error, the details of it, etc. All of that information will be beneficial to those willing to help.

One FYI though, I can see that you have tagged the question 8.5, but the last commit comment is "updated for SDL Tridion 2013 SP1" which may mean that the code is incompatible with 8.5.

Comment: We have used the code already and it works fine for CT's selection from it. However, when we click on the link for the Publications and StructureGroups it takes the type=1 in the URL and Structure groups don't show in the list. The "PopulateNode" method thats creating the nodes as per the solution in the github source looks fine, not sure how to tweak it to extract SG's in the pop-up as its doing for CT's